# Handling lost graphics device XNA 4.0 in winforms

Tags: xna

I'm trying to put in a new feature into my level editor. Part of the feature is to bring up a form when a user places a new tile onto the map, but once the form is brought up the XNA embedded screen throws up a big red X.  I think this is due to the embedded screen losing focus to the form and then crashing.

This is where the form is initialized

```
 public Form1()
   {
    InitializeComponent();

    //Node Editor

    tileDisplay1.OnInitialize += new EventHandler(tileDisplay1_OnInitialize);
    tileDisplay1.OnDraw += new EventHandler(tileDisplay1_OnDraw);

    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys[] allKeys = (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys[])
     Enum.GetValues(typeof(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys));

    foreach (var key in allKeys)
    KeyboardInput.AddKey(key);

     KeyboardInput.KeyRelease += new KeyHandler(KeyboardInput_KeyRelease);
     MouseInput.MouseMove += new MouseMoveHandler(MouseInput_MouseMove);
     MouseInput.MouseDown += new MouseClickHandler(MouseInput_MouseDown);
     MouseInput.MouseUp += new MouseClickHandler(MouseInput_MouseUp);

     Application.Idle += delegate { tileDisplay1.Invalidate(); };

     saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Map File|*.map";

     Mouse.WindowHandle = tileDisplay1.Handle;

   }
```

This is where the draw event is fired off

```
void tileDisplay1_OnDraw(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logic();
            Render();

            KeyboardInput.Update();
            MouseInput.Update();

            foreach (var actor in Actor.Actors)
                actor.Update();
        }
```

This is where the form is being called

```
     private void Logic()
    {
               if (colIndex == 8 && AssociateBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    currentCollisionLayer.SetCellIndex(collideCellX, collideCellY,form.spawnNumber.ToString());

                    if(form.spawnNumber == "12")
                    {
                       camdetails.ShowDialog();
                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered simply having a separate form that sits beside the main XNA game window and contains a reference to the game? That's what I did on my map editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Big Red X" from the WinForms sample comes up when your draw/update code throws an exception. Rather than simply ignoring it, the WinForms sample catches the exception, switches to displaying the Big Red X, and stops calling your draw/update code.

**This is the equivalent of a regular XNA programming exiting with an "Unhandled Exception" error.**

Simply resetting the graphics device and attempting to continue is the wrong solution.

What you need to do is figure out where the exception is being thrown, and stop it percolating up past your draw/update code. Try setting "break on exception" in Visual Studio. Or wrap your draw/update code in a try-catch block and adding a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reviewing the XNA AppHub sample on WinForms that is located here: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1

They create a `GraphicsDeviceService` derived from `IGraphicsDeviceService`. The `GraphicsDeviceService` updates `PresentationParameters` and calls `graphicsDevices.Reset(parameters);` any time the `GraphicsDevice` needs it, which is anytime the window or form resizes.

From the code you've posted I'm guessing that `camDetails.ShowDialog();` or something inside of `SetCellIndex` could be the cause.

As a quick test you might try this right before you call `Logic();`:

```
graphicsDeviceService.ResetDevice(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
```

Try calling that from your `Systems.Windows.Forms.Control`

Comment: The camDetails.ShowDialog(); is causing the issue, but I thought the graphics device could be reset when the call to it is made so that the screen doesn't crash or isn't that possible ?

Comment: I believe you should be able to create the dialog, reset the device, and then draw.

Comment: That should be doable, but the moment dialog is called it doesn't execute the next line and instead throws up the big red X, so I'm guessing it's throwing up an exception the debugger isn't catching

Comment: You might try wrapping the statement in a try/catch block to see if you can catch the exception.

Comment: My editor is based on this sample and it behaves well in the situations you described. I've never had problems opening new dialogs or switching windows, and I can even have multiple `GraphicsDeviceControl` objects created and rendering at the same time. I'd recommend starting from there too.